# Attributed type(Dictionary/array) missing for multi level JSON

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

i have this sample JSON file & after parsing i am using core data to store it

```
    {
       "Accounts":[
          {
             "accountname":"PNB",
             "accountnumber":"155666478",
             "mycredit":{
                "first_deposits":"$45345",
                "sec_deposits":"$37000",
             },
             "mydebits":{
                "payments":"$54000",
                "paid":"$62000",
             }
          },
    ...
]
}
```

So i have created an Account class (NSManagedObject subclass).
In account class, for account name & number, i am using string Attributed type. 
But for mycredit & mydebit i am not finding any dictionary attributed type.

So how to handle it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no built-in Core Data types for dictionaries. You have the following options:

- Flatten the structure and add 4 attributes "first_deposits", "sec_deposits", "payments"
  and "paid".
- Create additional entities "Credit" (with attributes "first_deposits", "sec_deposits")
  and "Debits" (with attributes "payments" and "paid"), and to-one relationships from "Account" to these entities.
- (You *could* also store a dictionary as a "transformable" attribute. Core data will then
  convert the dictionary to binary data for the SQLite store and back as necessary. But this has other implications, so that I would not recommend it here. For example, you could not use the dictionary keys
  in search predicates or Key-Value Coding methods.)